# Create a Core Graphics CALayer box with text in upper rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, calayer

I want to create a box like this with the text in the top of the box. Of course, I want solid lines instead of the dotted lines. For some reason the word this is displaying as blue but please ignore that.

```
 ——————— This is the title ——————————
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
 ———————————————————————————————————-
```

I'm using this code that creates the box but I'm looking for a way to get the title in the box lines rather than inside the box or on top of the box.

```
CALayer *bookViewlayer = self.bookView.layer;

[bookViewlayer setOpacity:40];

[bookViewlayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];

[bookViewlayer setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];

[bookViewlayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];

[bookViewlayer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think the easiest way is setting the background color of the label to the color behind the box lines.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Use two `UIView`s, `CALayer`s will not draw outside of their bounds. If you position two views correctly this can be achieved.

Comment: Yes, I know what you are saying Nikita, just use the UIView as lines of a box and leave an opening for text. Thanks